# ModuleNotFoundError: No module X when using PyDroid3

Tags: python, translate

I have made a Python 3 translator, but it shows an error when I run it. This is the code I have used:

```
from translate import Translator
s = Translator(from_lang=input('From.Language:'), to_lang=input('To.Language:'))
res = s.translate(input('Write your text: '))
print('res')
```

The error is ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kzGN.png)):

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'translate'
```

How can I fix this on an Android phone? I am using Pydroid3.

Comment: You're printing the literal string `'res'` instead of the variable `res`. replace the last line with `print(res)`

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Don't post errors as screenshots. Always copy paste them into your question

Comment: @Lecdi `name = value, name = value` is valid syntax when passing keyword arguments to functions, as in this case

Comment: You're developing on Android phone which does not have the `translate` package installed. That's the source of the `ModuleNotFoundError` in the screenshot.

Comment: Oops, didn't see it was in a function call

Comment: See if [this](https://www.makeuseof.com/install-pydroid-android/) makes any sense (is it up to date and does with work with [translate](https://pypi.org/project/translate/)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because the module is not installed in device. Before performing a Python project execution you should first install the package or pip from internet. For example for this question we need `translate` pip which will help you to run this project. You can first install pip in your device then can run the project for more read official [document](https://pypi.org/project/translate/)

Comment: That is an unspecific answer. What was the actual command line for solving the problem in the question? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72162303/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).